Example of a function that is differentiable only at points $x$ where $x$ is an integer
Give an example of a function $f: R \to R$ such that $f'(x)$ exists  for all $x$ where $x$ is an integer, but $f'(x)$ doesn't exist when $x$ is not an integer.
I know this is possible but how does one build this function?

Maybe start with the Dirichlet function and squeeze it flat at the integers with a scaled version of $\sin^2(x)$?...

Try $f(x) = 1_\mathbb{Q}(x) \sin^2 {2 \pi x}$.
